# When to modify constranints so it will override storyboard setup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

The problem of mine is, that I setup the constraints in the storyboard. But then I want to adapt it before the view appears on screen.

So for example if I lay down 5 views in a line and I want to hide one of then on smaller phones, where do I put the code for this. I tried `viewWillApper`, but the storyboard setup loads after that method and override my setup.

I found `viewDidLayoutSubviews` but now Im wondering if this is the best approach. Because I think this gets called many times later but I want some method that is called only after constraints are modifyed by storybord setup. So just before the main view appears on screen.

Hope you'll guide me in the right direction.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` should work fine. Actually, if you intend to set constraints up once, `viewDidLoad` will do. How do you modify constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint will finish setting when `viewDidLoad` gets called. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called by the system in proper time or when you change you orientation.

Comment: Great it works like a charm. Gues that I make something wrong back then in previous projects. Thanks for help